# Jquery Select all asp labels in a div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, label

How to select a list of asp labels within a div?

```
<div id="myDiv"> <asp:Label ID="myLabel".../> <asp:Label ID="myLabel".../> </div>
```

This Jquery code does not work.

```
$("#myDiv label").each(function(){ alert("show this msg");});
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myDiv span[id*=myLabel]").each(function(){ alert("show this msg");});
```

Since, a `asp:Label` is rendered as `span` in HTML.

Also, please give some unique **ID** to the asp labels like `myLabel1`, `myLabel2`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. marking this as an answer as it helped me get closer to what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
u can iterate through all lables inside `#mydiv`.use [`^ selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) which check the starting string

```
$("#myDiv span[id^=myLabel]").each(function(){ alert("show this msg");});
```